# How to connect to an Oracle Database running on Amazon AWS EC2?

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle Database instance running in Amazon AWS EC2 service.  (it is not RDS Relational Database Services).

How can I configure my Oracle SQl Developer to to access this remote databse in AWS EC2?

By checking AWS documentation I found only references to connect to Oracle databse running in RDS services.

I apreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but is there a particular reason why you chose to host your own Oracle instance outside of RDS?  AWS is setup to make integrating with RDS from EC2 almost seamless; it's much more work to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Tim,  the reason is for development and test purposes for short period.  By the way has AWS a free instance of RDS service like it has for EC2 ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that certain databases may have free tier packages available, at least for a while (e.g. MySQL).  Not sure about Oracle, though.

Comment: Well, the RDS documentation will give you a hint of how to configure `security group`. This is similar to configuring your EC2 so other IP can connect to it.

Comment: sqldev doesn't care where your db is, but we have to be able to reach your network/ip/port - so check your network/firewall settings. but what you could do is just open up port 22, and use a SSH tunnel in

Answer (score 1):

1. In AWS, edit the Security Group for your instance to add a rule (if one doesn't already exist).

   **Inbound**

   **Type** = SSH

   **Protocol** = TCP

   **Port Range** = 22

   **Source** = "My IP", or "Custom" (as you wish)
2. In SQL Developer, open View -> **SSH**.
3. Right-click "SSH Hosts", **New SSH Host**.

   **Name** = *whatever you like*

   **Host** = *your server's IPv4 Public IP address*

   **Port** = 22 (default)

   **Username** = `root` or `ec2-user`, whichever is appropriate for the linux AMI you used

   **Use key file** = tick this and select your key file for your instance

   **Add a Local Port Forward** = tick this and accept the defaults (localhost, port 1521)
4. Edit the properties of your SQL Developer Database Connection

   **Connection Type** = SSH

   **Port Forward** = the name of the SSH Host you created earlier

   **SID** / **Service name** = whatever SID or Service name you need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another layer of security. SSH or DMZ + Load Balancing is the way to go. If not Make sure the following are all open for the IP. firewall, VPC Network, AWS inbound outbound rules.