# Connecting oracle XE db on AWS EC2 - configure TNSLIstenr for internal and external IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-ec2, listener, oracle-xe

I am trying to connect to an Oracle XE instance on an AWS EC2 instance. I found this answer: [Connecting dto an oracle database running on ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885656/how-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database-running-on-amazon-aws-ec2). The answer gave some info which I had found already , and talks about using SSH if the ports are blocked. But I don't think that is the problem here.

All AWS EC2 instances have both an internal and external IP. By default, the XE install configured tnsnames and listener for the internal IP. Is it possible to configure the listener for both IPs? When I was a wee baby, I worked at Oracle. Even back then I remember having trouble with these files. Now in my senile old age, I have no clue.

Comment: Do you just mean [listening on two addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746373/266304)?

Comment: Sorry if I use the wrong terms here. As I said, Oracle network config has alwasy done my head in.
Below is what is on the server, in listenr.ora. The IP is the internal IP on the AWS instance Using that I can run sqldeveloper or DBeaver or whatever on the server. What I want to do is add (not replace) the external facing IP so that I can also connect from my laptop.

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

```

Comment: Yes - that's what the answer I linked to shows. That is listening on both localhost (127.0.0.1) and 192.168.10.110. You can do the same, by adding an ADDRESS_LIST level and then an extra HOST/PORT entry - just use your own internal and external IP addresses (or host names if you prefer). The `tnsnames.ora` on each client needs to use the appropriate IP/hostname - so within AWS you probably don't want to change that; on your laptop you'd use the external address, in ``tnsnames.ora` if you use that, or just in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

@alex-poole, thanks for the help.
Had to make a few more changes to get everything working.

The default config in TNSNAMES and Listner has too much and seems to break if as soon as you add something new. I got rid of anything that was not essential.

1. In TNSNAMES I left a single config, for the service name as opposed to SID, and added the external IP as you suggested.

```
XE =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)(PORT = 1521))
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
   )
 )
```

2. In the Listner file, I just set XE service as default.

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE
```

3. With that above config, I was able to connect SQLDeveloper on the server.
4. By using the SSH connection in SQLDeveloper I was then able to connect from my laptop.

Comment: If you're using SSH then you aren't using the external address for the listener - and if you haven't added it to `listener.ora` then it won't be listening on that anyway (`lsnrctl status` will show you what it's currently doing). Modifying the `tnsnames.ora` probably didn't do anything as you could already connect from the server, and no impact on connections from elsewhere. But glad you got in anyway *8-)

Answer (score 0):

@alex-poole, I was thinking exactly the same thing about the SSH, but it wasn't working without it. So could you help me understand what is actually going on here? On the server, you see that I have put both IPs into TNSNAMES under the XE service (is that the right way to refer to it?)
Then in the Listener.ora, I am just pointing to the XE service am I not?

On the server, this is the output of `lsnrctl status`

```
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                04-APR-2023 12:39:14
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 19 min. 54 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Administrator\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Administrator\product\21c\diag\tnslsnr\EC2AMAZ-21HKFFG\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=[AWSHOSTNAME])(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\PRODUCT\21C\admin\XE\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "d87270c138ed4411b8c05fba94d15f4a" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

So the xe instance seems to have created the services XE, XEDB, d87270c138ed4411b8c05fba94d15f4a, xedb1 services? I'm don't think I know what that means.

On the client side, I have neither tnsnames nor listener, which I why I guess I need to use the SSH connection? I installed the oracle instant client, but I don't see anything to indicate that sqldev is using that in any way.

This is the connection attempt without SSH (doesn't work)
[image]

This is the connection with SSH (does work)
[image]